# protoc did not exit cleanly and Missing: ---------- 1) com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:${os.detected.classifier}:3.6.1

Tags: java, maven, protocol-buffers, maven-plugin, grpc-java

I am trying to build maven, every time when I build on `eclipse` using `maven update` getting

```
Missing: ---------- 1) 
com.google.protobuf:protoc:exe:${os.detected.classifier}:3.6.1 error.
```

From the `command line` I am getting below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven- 
plugin:0.5.1:compile (default) on project ivf-sample: protoc did not exit 
cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]
```

any suggestion experts on how to resolve this error ?

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>
                        com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.6.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>
                        io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.22.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                    </pluginArtifact>
                    <protoSourceRoot>
                        ${basedir}/src/main/proto/
                    </protoSourceRoot>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: protoc 3.6.1 is pretty old, you may want to try with some newer version. Also, I'd recommend using the same grpc version for `protoc-gen-grpc-java` (aka, 1.32.1).

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the following code snippet in pom.xml, and I was able to successfully build my Maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>tutorial1-server</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>1.36.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.36.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.36.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.36.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                <protoSourceRoot>src/main/resources</protoSourceRoot>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

eclipse May not get the properties of value: ${os.detected.classifier} so you can config it on maven settings.xml at profiles.profile.properties.

<os.detected.classifier>windows-x86_64</os.detected.classifier>